# Add a formula based column using Views UI - Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have made a view that has one column for the total of posts from a user and another column for the number of views of those posts.

Is there any way to create a third column where I can show the ratio of views per posts using Views UI in Drupal of those already calculated fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with the math and php user drupal.org/project/views_php

Add a php field, your values will be available in the "available variable" drop down, use the "output code" section to print or echo out ratio